# Angular 2 Custom Validator

Tags: angular, typescript

I did upgrade of my project and my validators does not working anymore.

My validator:

```
import {Directive, Provider, forwardRef, Input} from '@angular/core';
import {NG_VALIDATORS, Validator, FormControl} from '@angular/forms';

const ANO_MES_CC_VALIDATOR = { provide: NG_VALIDATORS, useExisting:       forwardRef(() => AnoMesCcValidator), multi: true };

declare var jQuery: JQueryStatic;

@Directive({
    selector: '[ano-mes-cc-validator]',
    providers: [ANO_MES_CC_VALIDATOR]
})
export class AnoMesCcValidator implements Validator {

    constructor() { }

    validate(c: FormControl): { [key: string]: any } {

        if (c.value == undefined || c.value == "") {
            //return null;
            return { 'anoMesccValidation': 'Validade Inválida.' };
        }

        var mes = c.value.substring(0, 2);
        var ano = c.value.substring(3, 7);

        //Verifica se o ano está correto
        if (ano.length == 4 && ano > 1900 && ano < 2100 && mes > 0 && mes <     13 ) {
            //valid
            return null;
        }
        else {
            return { 'anoMesccValidation': 'Validade Inválida.' };
        }
    }             
}
```

My Typescript

```
import {AnoMesCcValidator} from '../../validators/index';

this.formCartaoDeCredito = new FormGroup({
        anoMesCartaoDeCreditoControl: new FormControl('anoMesCartaoDeCreditoControl', [Validators.required])
    });
```

My Template:

```
<form [formGroup]="formCartaoDeCredito" role="form">
<div class="row">
<div class="col-xs-7 col-md-7">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="cardExpiry"><span class="hidden-xs">Vencimento</span><span class="visible-xs-inline">EXP</span></label>
        <input class="form-control"
               placeholder="MM / YYYY"
               autocomplete="cc-exp"
               onkeyup="formataMesAno(event)"
               maxlength="7"
               ano-mes-cc-validator
               formControlName="anoMesCartaoDeCreditoControl"
               [(ngModel)]="cartaoCredito.Validade" />
    </div>
</div>
```

So, does not work, the error is 'Cannot read property 'valid' of undefined', i've already set #anoMesCartaoDeCreditoControl

Comment: ngModel should not be use with model driven forms.